# Prince XML on Heroku

Tags: heroku, service, server, princexml

I'm working with a Node JS deployment on Heroku, and was wondering if anyone knew how to deploy Prince to Heroku and then access it as a service from an API call.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/docraptor is what you're looking for. DocRaptor uses the Prince PDF engine, in addition to a separate JavaScript engine.

Comment: Well, I did it for Java. Executed: "heroku create --buildpack heroku/java" and "heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/lm-tools/heroku-buildpack-princexml.git". After you deploy your code Prince will be installed at "/app/bin/prince". I think you should only change the first build pack to something similar to "heroku create --buildpack heroku/nodejs"